Question with multiple variables
I'm new in the community.
I have a problem trying to get the domain of a function, graph that and get level curves. My function is separated in conditions:
if (x,y) ≠ 0
( $
x^2$*y)/( $
x^3$+ $
y^3$) ,
0 if (x,y)=0
First I tried to obtain the domain of the function:
$
x^3$+ $
y^3$ ≠ 0
$
-x^3$ ≠  $
y^3$
-x ≠ y (apply cube square)
That's is a linear function, and all the values in this graphic are not part of the domain of the function, right? And the point f(0,0) is not in the domain of the function because is part of the restriction in f, right?
Then, the exercise asks me to obtain the level curves that pass for the point (1,2). I evaluate that point in f(x,y), I get a value that I understand is K in the level curve (2/9 is the result to evaluate (1,2)):
K = $
x^2$*y / $
x^3$+$
y^3$
2/9 = $
x^2$*y / $
x^3$+$
y^3$
but how can i order that ecuation (pass x for a side, or y, etc), to get a familiar ecuation to graph? Because I think I'll get the two variables of each side and its hard to get a solution with that
Thanks!

hard or not to read, no parenthesis , no mathjax.

Yes, hard to read. I tried to edit, but seems others are in queue.

Sorry, I edited the post! I hope it undertand. Thanks!
